# How can I make the name of a variable be "NameOfVariable_[XdaysFromToday]"? (so the name changes every today)?

Tags: python

I want to register my weight every day and calculate the average of the last 7 days.

Therefore, the average will have to be calculated with the following weights:

```
Day 0 = 80 [the weight today]
Day -1 = 79
Day -2 = 78.5
... 
Day -6 = 78
```

Therefore, what today is "Day 0", tomorrow will be "Day -1" and so on.

How would you deal with the name of the variables?

Thanks

Comment: This is where you use a list.

Comment: you could also use a dict. have keys like `Day -1` so forth. it would work if you want to access a value like `d['Day -20']` - which you cannot with a list, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the problem statement:

```
"""
Day 0 = 80 [the weight today]
Day -1 = 79
Day -2 = 78.5
...
Day -6 = 78
"""
```

You could use a custom `list` implementation as below:

```py
class DaysList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item, __get=list.__getitem__):
        if item > 0:
            raise ValueError(f'unexpected behavior ({item!r} > 0), '
                             'raising an error to be safe.')
        # noinspection PyArgumentList
        return __get(self, -item)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__qualname__}<{self!r}>'


days = DaysList([80, 79, 78.5])

print(days)

assert days[0] == 80
assert days[-2] == 78.5
```

Output:

```
DaysList<[80, 79, 78.5]>
```